# How to determine which text within a scrolling text display window is visible?

Tags: css, scroll, metadata, word-wrap

We designed a web interface to display text in a scrollable element and to track scrolling events when someone scrolls to read the text. We set the textual display features using CSS. Now we have a record of what text was displayed, and a record of what the window size was (or sized if the user re-sized the window at some point). All events are timestamped. We want to develop a record of how long each portion of the text was displayed to the user as they navigated by scrolling. I thought there would be many examples of code to do this, but I don't find anything.

So, can someone refer me to a resource of how I might be able to calculate based on the font size, line width/height settings, and display size of a scrollable text window, how to determine which range of the text was displayed given a certain scrolling indicator?

Many thanks for any leads.

Comment: Please share any relevant code that you have attempted so far.

Comment: Rather than do all this math have you considered InstersectionObserver on different sections of text? It would be less exactly accurate but you would not have to deal with the user randomly changing text size/zooming and so on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.